# XAML bind to indexed element in property of binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Given this object

```
class Contact 
{
     public IEnumerable<Person> People { get; }
     public string PhoneNumber { get; }
}

class Person
{
     public string MobileNumber { get; }
}
```

And the following layout

```
<Contact>
    <PhoneNumber/>
    <SinglePerson.MobileNumber/>
    <People>
       <MobileNumber />
    </People>
<Contact>
```

What I'd like to do is hide the People element when there is only one person, and show the SinglePerson.Mobile number element instead.

Hiding is fairly easy:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=People.Count}" Value="1">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Showing is slightly more tricky:

```
<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>   
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=People.Count}" Value="1">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

The thing that I can't work out how to do is to bind the `<SinglePerson.MobileNumber>` Text to the first person in the People list. I've tried variants of "{Binding People[0].MobilePhone}", but that doesn't work.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually far easier, if you only want to get the FIRST item in a collection. If you reference the desired property, wpf automatically picks the value for the first element in the collection:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding People/MobileNumber}" Value="">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</DataTrigger>
```

(from [IanG](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/09/03/bindtocurrent))

Answer (score 2):

There may be other ways, but I have solved this in the past by creating a value converter (a class named PersonIndexerConverter that implements IValueConverter).  The conversion can take a parameter which is your index.  Pass the index as a parementer in the XAML.  The binding becomes a tad more complicated, but you get your indexing.

Comment: Cool, works ok for me, I've made a FirstPersonMobileConverter (I could have decided to pass in the Property name as parameter, that will be for the next version).